# Moq how to replace obsolete expression

Tags: linq, moq

I'm using Moq in my code. I wrote an expression like:

```
mockInvoice.VerifySet(x => x.InvoiceAttachmentId, Times.Once());
```

Where `InvoiceAttachmentId` is a property on my Invoice.

It works fine but I get the warning:

> Moq.MockExtensions.VerifySet(Moq.Mock,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>,
>   Moq.Times)' is obsolete: 'Replaced by  VerifySet(Action, Times)'

Can anyone tell me how to rewrite it to satisfy the compiler and get rid of the warning? I'm unsure how to make the replacement to Action.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
mockInvoice.VerifySet(x => x.InvoiceAttachmentId = 123, Times.Once());
```

Replace 123 with the expected value.

If you want to permit any value, use:

```
mockInvoice.VerifySet(x => x.InvoiceAttachmentId = It.IsAny<int>(),
    Times.Once());
```