# Moq VerifySet(Action) replacing obsolete expression compilation error

Tags: c#, moq

Referring to this question:

[Moq how to replace obsolete expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935906/moq-how-to-replace-obsolete-expression)

I have the following:

```
[Test]
public void OnSearchRequest_ViewFiresEvent_EventIsHandled()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IViewUsers> view = new Mock<IViewUsers>();
    Users users = new Users(view.Object);

    // Act
    view.Raise(v => v.SearchForUsers += null, this, new SearchEventArgs());

    // Assert
    view.VerifySet(v=> v.SearchResult = It.IsAny<List<IUser>>());

}
```

originally I had:

```
        // Assert
        view.VerifySet(v => v.SearchResult);
```

But was getting the warning:

> 'Moq.MockExtensions.VerifySet(Moq.Mock,
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' is
>   obsolete: 'Replaced by VerifySet(Action)'

So I found the question referenced above, and changed it to match, but now I'm STILL getting that warning, and on top of that, a hard error on "v.SearchResult" within the call to VerifySet :

> An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator.

I can't see that I'm formatting this improperly - so why isn't it recognizing this as an action as the other question implies it should?

Comment: Which version of Moq are you using? Because I've created a small repro with 4.0.10827.0 and it's green and compiles without the obsolete warning... You should provide more context how the classes in your test look like.

Comment: What more context would you like?

Comment: Here is my repro: https://gist.github.com/d1f858b12be689a5e32f. You can test it and maybe you will see something...

Comment: That's frustrating as hell.  Your VerifySet code is *exactly* the same as what I posted.  NOW?  NOW it compiles.

Comment: Anyway if you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found something relatively close to what you are asking about. [Moq how to replace obsolete expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935906/moq-how-to-replace-obsolete-expression) I don't know if this helps because I only ever used `mock.Setup` and `mock.Verify`.

Also as mentioned before try using lambda expressions within your `It.IsAny` to pinpoint smaller things this way . If a verify fails you know exactly where it failed. Especially if you are expecting a value at a certain position for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but I've had problems in the past using `It.IsAny<>` with lists. Could you try something like `It.Is<List<IUser>>(l => l != null)`?